# Reference request for vertex correction of electron-phonon interaction beyond Migdal's theorem

Tags: condensed-matter, resource-recommendations, superconductivity, many-body

I am considering the calculation of the vertex correction due to electron-phonon interactions. Specifically, I am looking for solutions to the integral (Eqn. 1)

$$\int dq G(q)D(q-p)G(p+k)$$

where $dq=d^4q/(2\pi)^2$. The fermionic Green's function is given by

$$G_\sigma(p,\,\omega)=\frac{Z}{\omega-v_F(|p|-p_\sigma)+i\delta_\sigma}$$

where $Z$ is the quasiparticle weight, and the Goldstone propagator is given by

$$D_G=-\frac{N(0)v_F}{2}\frac{\omega_s(q)}{(\omega+i\delta)^2-\omega_s^2}$$

where $\omega_s\sim q^2$. When I have seen the calculation done before, the bosonic propagator puts bounds on the integration limits. This is discussed in ["Interaction between Electrons and Lattice Vibrations in a Normal Metal", by A.B. Migdal.](http://www.jetp.ac.ru/cgi-bin/e/index/e/7/6/p996?a=list) However, I am interested in explicitly calculating the vertex correction given the explicit form of the phonon propagator, similar to what is done in [K. B. Blagoev, J. R. Engelbrecht, and K. S. Bedell
Phys. Rev. Lett. 82, 133 (1999)](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.82.133).

I would therefore like to request references that explicitly calculate integrals of the form Eqn. 1. Unfortunately, all the major textbooks I have resort to Migdal's theorem, and do not explicitly calculate the integral out.  Anything at the level of Mahan would be appreciated, but I am more partial to open source, online references if possible. I am also open to someone answering with a direct solution of the above integral, but I am more interested in the current literature on the topic (as I have been able to find very little). I have my own calculation, but I would like to check my work and see other people's methods.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why you're interested in references but not interested in someone showing you how to do it in an answer?

Comment: @DavidZ I have clarified the question. I am open to a direct solution, however I am more interested in the literature as I have found very few references that actually do the calculation for some odd reason.